# tensorflow training freezes randomly on kaggle tpu

Tags: python, tensorflow, conv-neural-network, generative-adversarial-network, tpu

I'm using kaggle TPU to train a tensorflow CycleGAN model. Everything is fine after training starts, but training freezes randomly after a few models. RAM has not exploded during training according to kaggle.

I've met with warnings during training as such:

```
2022-11-28 07:22:58.323282: W ./tensorflow/core/distributed_runtime/eager/destroy_tensor_handle_node.h:57] Ignoring an error encountered when deleting remote tensors handles: Invalid argument: Unable to find the relevant tensor remote_handle: Op ID: 89987, Output num: 0
Additional GRPC error information from remote target /job:worker/replica:0/task:0:
:{"created":"@1669620178.323159560","description":"Error received from peer ipv4:10.0.0.2:8470","file":"external/com_github_grpc_grpc/src/core/lib/surface/call.cc","file_line":1056,"grpc_message":"Unable to find the relevant tensor remote_handle: Op ID: 89987, Output num: 0","grpc_status":3}
Epoch 5/200
```

When I'm configuring the TPUs I've warnings as:

```
2022-11-28 13:56:35.038036: I tensorflow/compiler/jit/xla_cpu_device.cc:41] Not creating XLA devices, tf_xla_enable_xla_devices not set
2022-11-28 13:56:35.040789: W tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:60] Could not load dynamic library 'libcuda.so.1'; dlerror: libcuda.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory; LD_LIBRARY_PATH: /opt/conda/lib
2022-11-28 13:56:35.040821: W tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_driver.cc:326] failed call to cuInit: UNKNOWN ERROR (303)
2022-11-28 13:56:35.040850: I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_diagnostics.cc:156] kernel driver does not appear to be running on this host (06e37d3ac4e4): /proc/driver/nvidia/version does not exist
2022-11-28 13:56:35.043518: I tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:142] This TensorFlow binary is optimized with oneAPI Deep Neural Network Library (oneDNN) to use the following CPU instructions in performance-critical operations:  AVX2 FMA
To enable them in other operations, rebuild TensorFlow with the appropriate compiler flags.
2022-11-28 13:56:35.044759: I tensorflow/compiler/jit/xla_gpu_device.cc:99] Not creating XLA devices, tf_xla_enable_xla_devices not set
2022-11-28 13:56:35.079672: I tensorflow/core/distributed_runtime/rpc/grpc_channel.cc:301] Initialize GrpcChannelCache for job worker -> {0 -> 10.0.0.2:8470}
2022-11-28 13:56:35.079743: I tensorflow/core/distributed_runtime/rpc/grpc_channel.cc:301] Initialize GrpcChannelCache for job localhost -> {0 -> localhost:30020}
2022-11-28 13:56:35.098707: I tensorflow/core/distributed_runtime/rpc/grpc_channel.cc:301] Initialize GrpcChannelCache for job worker -> {0 -> 10.0.0.2:8470}
2022-11-28 13:56:35.098760: I tensorflow/core/distributed_runtime/rpc/grpc_channel.cc:301] Initialize GrpcChannelCache for job localhost -> {0 -> localhost:30020}
2022-11-28 13:56:35.101231: I tensorflow/core/distributed_runtime/rpc/grpc_server_lib.cc:411] Started server with target: grpc://localhost:30020
```

Tensorflow version is 2.4.1, other configs I haven't touched. My `model.fit` function looks like such:

```
history = gan_model.fit(gan_ds, 
                        epochs=EPOCHS, 
                        callbacks=[GANMonitor()], 
                        steps_per_epoch=(max(n_monet_samples, n_photo_samples)//BATCH_SIZE), 
                        verbose=2,
                        workers=0).history
```

Most parts of the code comes from a kaggle tutorial, but I've changed the model architecture. Is there a way to solve this issue?

I've tried configuring it to `verbose=1` and saw that training freezes on a random step in the middle of an epoch. The number of epochs I'm able to go through seems to be depending on the model architecture and batchsize, so I think there's some issue with memory?

Comment: A gRPC status code of `3` indicates `Invalid Argument`.

Comment: Are there any specific meanings to this status code? like are there issues with input images?

Answer (score 0):

I tried to run below two tutorials on v3-8 and I encountered similar warnings in both the runs.

1. https://www.kaggle.com/code/philculliton/a-simple-petals-tf-2-2-notebook
2. https://www.kaggle.com/code/amyjang/monet-cyclegan-tutorial

But they didn't break the training.

Could you please check if the original tutorial code runs for a significant number of epochs? If yes, you might need to review your changes to the model architecture.

Also, if batch_size is affecting the number of training epochs, then most probably it's an Out of Memory error. Try reducing the batch_size preferably to a factor of 128 per core and see if the run completes.

More resources -

1. How improper batch_size can lead to OOM - https://cloud.google.com/tpu/docs/performance-guide#xla-efficiencies
2. Profiling guide - https://cloud.google.com/tpu/docs/cloud-tpu-tools

Feel free to explore our in-depth guides on TPUs with excellent tutorials - https://cloud.google.com/tpu/docs/intro-to-tpu